# Cucumber cannot find step definitions in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, cucumber

I've integrated Cucumber with Android Studio. It seems that Android Studio can find the right file to place steps definitions because it suggests to implement them from the `.feature` file into the correct `.java` file. However, when I run the feature it says that the steps are undefined.

Here is the grade dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.0.14'
    androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.5'
}
```

The Cucumber configuration

```
package app.waxbee.stepdefinitions;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "resources/features", glue = "app.waxbee.stepdefinitions")
public class CucumberTestCase {

}
```

And the project structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKWSH.png

I'm new with this framework so if you see anything that can be improved I deeply appreciate your teachings for improvement. Thank you in advance.